# Netbeans project libraries - Compile-time libs vs Run-time libs

Tags: java, netbeans, java-module, openjdk-12

## Brief description

In a netbeans project, if I tell Netbeans that a specific jar file is to be made available on the **compile-time** classpath as a library, then, I understand that Netbeans would also make that jar file available on the **run-time** classpath. But this classpath lib "propagation" seems to work only in a non-modular project, and doesn't seem to be happening in the case of a Modular project (in Netbeans 11).

## My experiment

I've created 3 simple, experimental projects, called `ProjectA`, `ProjectB`, `ProjectC`, in Netbeans 11. The IDE, as well as the 3 projects, are configured to run on `Open Jdk12`.

#### ProjectA

`ProjectA` is non-modular, and just defines `pkg1.MyClassA`

#### ProjectB

`ProjectB` is also non-modular, and defines `pkg2.MyClassB` which imports and extends `pkg1.MyClassA`. In `ProjectB`'s Properties==>Libraries==>Compile, I have specified `ProjectA/dist/ProjectA.jar` file as a required classpath library. In `ProjectB`'s Run options (ProjectB Properties==>Libraries==>Run) I have not specified this jar dependence. At runtime, `MyClassA` will be needed, because the `main()` method of `MyClassB` instantiates `MyClassB` which extends `MyClassA`.

#### ProjectC

`ProjectC` is Modular (created with Netbeans option NewProject==>JavaWithAnd==>JavaModularProject). It defines `mod.world/pkg3.MyClassC`, which has a `main()` method that instantiates `pkg1.MyClassA`. In `ProjectC`'s Properties==>Libraries==>Compile, I have specified ProjectA/dist/ProjectA.jar file as a required classpath library, just as I did for `ProjectB`'s dependence on `ProjectA.jar`. Also, I did not specify any jar dependence in `ProjectC`'s Properties==>Libraries==>Run, just as in the case of `ProjectB`'s properties. Also, I have specified `--add-reads mod.world=ALL-UNNAMED` in `ProjectC`'s compiler option as well as a runtime JVM option, to enable the explicit module of `ProjectC` to access the unnamed module of `ProjectA.jar`, at both compile-time and runtime.

The `Compile on save` option is turned off for all the 3 projects.

## What I expected

I expected to be able to successfully compile and run all the 3 Projects.

## What I actually saw

`ProjectA` compiled successfully.
`ProjectB` also compiled and ran successfully.
`ProjectC` compiled successfully, but failed at runtime with `NoClassDefFoundError` for not finding `pkg1.MyClassA`. This runtime error goes away if, in `ProjectC`'s Properties==>Libraries==>Run, I specify `ProjectA.jar` as a required classpath library (as I had specified in `ProjectC` Properties==>Libraries==>Compile).

## My Questions

1. The Netbeans dialog window at Project Properties==>Library, says

> "Compile-time libraries are propagated to all library categories"

. I understand that this was the reason why I was able to successfully run ProjectB, even though I had not specified any jar-file dependency at runtime for ProjectB, upon ProjectA.jar. So, why doesn't the same propagation happen in the case of ProjectC? Is it somehow because of ProjectC being a modular application? (Even if so, why?). Or is this a bug in Netbeans 11? (I did google for this before posting here).

2. What if, on some occasion, I wanted to stop Netbeans from propagating a compile-time library to run-time or to test-time? Is there a way to do that? For both modular and non-modular projects?

## Here's the complete code

#### Code for ProjectA

```
package pkg1;

public class MyClassA {
    public MyClassA(){
        System.out.println ("Inside constructor MyClassA()");
    }
}
```

#### Code for ProjectB

```
package pkg2;

import pkg1.MyClassA;

public class MyClassB {
    public MyClassB() {
        new MyClassA();
        System.out.println ("Inside constructor MyClassB()");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("Inside main() of MyClassB");
        new MyClassB();
    }
}
```

#### Code for ProjectC

**Code in module-info.java**

```
module mod.world {
    exports pkg3;
}
```

**Code in MyClassC.java**

```
package pkg3;

import pkg1.MyClassA;

public class MyClassC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClassA();
        System.out.println ("Inside main() method of MyClassC");
    }
}
```